# Harmonic Analysis: How would you interpret these 4 bars? Var. 18 Rhapsody by Rach

Tags: chords, harmony, analysis

Great community I've stumbled upon. It's been some time since I've done harmonic analysis and I'd appreciate some thoughts about these four bars towards the end of the 18th Variation.

[image: Rachmaninoff, "Rhapsody on ... Paganini", var 18, mm. 671 – 674]

Comment: Is this a condensed score, part of a transcription, or the actual piano part at this point? I recall the Rhapsody on a Theme of Paganini to be a piece for piano and orchestra.

Comment: @Dekkadeci You're correct — piano and orchestra. This is from the actual piano part.

Answer (score 4):

Well, that's a doozy!

#### Basic observations:

- Measure 1 = Measure 2 (transposed by whole step)
- Measure 3 = Measure 4 (intensified)
- The underlying structure relies on voice-leading (in the form of linear chromatic movement) as much as common-practice dissonance-resolution (such as V-I cadences). Once the ear hears something moving in a certain direction — even if that thing is dissonant — it will "understand" if that thing keeps moving in the same direction.

#### Harmonic outline (with groovy colored note heads)

**Layer 1: static (red)**
Layer 1. Db pedal tone — all four measures

**Layer 2: core melody and harmony (blue)**
Layer 2a. Descending chromatic line (top voice) — first two measures
Layer 2b. A diminished seventh chord — (end of) second two measures

**Layer 3: chromatic voice-leading (green and magenta)**
Layer 3a. Inverted C augmented sixth chord (spelled as C7) leading to B major (spelled enharmonically — BM7 including the Bb as A#) — first measure
Layer 3b. Inverted Ab augmented sixth chord (spelled enharmonically) leading to Gb minor (enharmonic) — second measure.
Layer 3c. Chromatic dominant seventh chords from Ab7 to B7 (which transforms to A diminished when B moves to C) — third measure.
Layer 4c. Chromatic dominant seventh chords with raised fifth again from Ab7 to B7 — fourth measure.

#### Colorized excerpt

[image: Colorized excerpt]

#### Colorized with analytical levels reduced and separated

[image: Colorized on three grand staves — one for each level]

Comment: I think this was the kind of thing familiar to Art Tatum...

Comment: As in Chopin and as in Tatum, many of the passing chords (seem to me to) serve very ephemeral harmonic functions, and are as much based on voice-leading ideas in voicing as on "harmony". I was reminded of this idea yesterday in hearing Mahler's 9th, where an over-commitment to harmonic analysis makes it fairly unintelligible, while voice-leading and voicing ideas make things far more "obvious".

Comment: @paulgarrett the same is frequently true in Bach.

Comment: A lot of very nice things here. One other big thing to bear in mind: this is a development/elaboration of several earlier passages — most closely, 14 bars earlier (just before Figure 51 in the 1934 Boosey & Hawkes edition), but also the parallel passages in the preceding variations.  So they may shed some light on this too.  In particular, these shed light on the enharmonic ambiguity of the final lingering A♮/B — here, several things pull towards hearing it as a raised 5th (though it still resolves downwards), but in some earlier analogous passages, there is unambiguously a flattened 6th.